# Android toolochain and proxy configuration error in flutter android studio IDE occur any solutions?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

```
PS C:\dev> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.316], locale en-      US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Professional 2022 17.8.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[!] Proxy Configuration
    ! NO_PROXY is not set
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

Tried to create a testapp but following errors occured. By removing proxy
PS E:\Test\flutter_application_1> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.316], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Professional 2022 17.8.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[!] Network resources
    X A network error occurred while checking "https://pub.dev/": Failed host lookup: 'pub.dev'
    X A network error occurred while checking "https://storage.googleapis.com/": Failed host  lookup: 'storage.googleapis.com'
    X A network error occurred while checking "https://maven.google.com/": Failed host lookup:   'maven.google.com'
    X A network error occurred while checking "https://cocoapods.org/": Failed host lookup: 'cocoapods.org'
    X A network error occurred while checking "https://github.com/": Failed host lookup:   'github.com'
```

and by adding toolchain and proxy cofiguration.......tried everything but all in vain. Stuck in this from weeks. Anyone please guide

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link. I hope this will be helpful for you :

```
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41034
```

- If it does not work then try this one **Disable firewalls and
  anti-virus**
- Or you can use **vpn** to download Sdk
- for window, you can use 'set' on cmd

  set https_proxy=hostname:port
  set NO_PROXY=hostname:port